# Parallelizing backtrack on sudoku not increasing the %cpu utilized

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, g++, openmp, sudoku

We're two students who are working on parallelize a 16x16 sudoku solver code. The solver uses backtrack, and our idea is to parallelize it with omp takes, every branch of the backtrack is supposed to be a new task.
The full code is this one, and it's a modification of [this one from github](https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/Sudoku-Solver/blob/master/Source.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <omp.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define DIM 16
#define BLANK 0
#define SPACE " "
#define LINE "|"
#define NEW_ROW "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
#define GRID_FULL std::make_pair(16, 16)

// Prints the Soduko grid
void print_grid(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    {
        cout << SPACE << SPACE << SPACE << SPACE << endl;
        cout << NEW_ROW << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
        {
            cout << SPACE;
            if (BLANK == grid[i][j])
            {
                cout << SPACE;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << grid[i][j];
            }
            cout << SPACE;
            cout << LINE;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << NEW_ROW << endl << endl;;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether any assigned entry
// in the specified row matches the given number. 
bool used_in_row(int grid[DIM][DIM], int row, int num)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < DIM; col++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
        {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether any assigned entry
// in the specified column matches the given number. 
bool used_in_col(int grid[DIM][DIM], int col, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < DIM; row++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
        {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether any assigned entry
// within the specified 3x3 box matches the given number. 
bool used_in_box(int grid[DIM][DIM], int box_start_rpw, int box_start_col, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            if (grid[row + box_start_rpw][col + box_start_col] == num) 
            {
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether it will be legal to assign
// num to the given row,col location.
bool is_safe(int grid[DIM][DIM], int row, int col, int num)
{
    // Check if 'num' is not already placed in current row,
    // current column and current 3x3 box 
    return !used_in_row(grid, row, num) &&
        !used_in_col(grid, col, num) &&
        !used_in_box(grid, row - row % 4, col - col % 4, num);
}

// Searches the grid to find an entry that is still unassigned. If
// found, the reference parameters row, col will be set the location
// that is unassigned, and true is returned. If no unassigned entries
// remain, false is returned. 
std::pair<int, int> get_unassigned_location(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < DIM; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < DIM; col++)
            if (grid[row][col] == BLANK)
            {
                return std::make_pair(row, col);
            }
    return GRID_FULL;
}

bool solve_soduko3(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    // If the Soduko grid has been filled, we are done
    if (GRID_FULL == get_unassigned_location(grid))
    {
   //omp cancel 
        return true; 
    }

    // Get an unassigned Soduko grid location
    std::pair<int, int> row_and_col = get_unassigned_location(grid);
    int row = row_and_col.first;
    int col = row_and_col.second;

    // Consider digits 1 to 16 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
    {
        // If placing the current number in the current
        // unassigned location is valid, go ahead
    //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    //printf("Executing thread: %d with number: %d\n" ,iam, num);
        if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            // Make tentative assignment
      //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
      //printf("Is_safe from thread: %d\n",iam);
            grid[row][col] = num;

            // Do the same thing again recursively. If we go 
            // through all of the recursions, and in the end 
            // return true, then all of our number placements 
            // on the Soduko grid are valid and we have fully
            // solved it
            if (solve_soduko3(grid))
            { 
        //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Solution from thread %d\n",iam);
        print_grid(grid);
                exit(true);
        return true;
            }

            // As we were not able to validly go through all 
            // of the recursions, we must have an invalid number
            // placement somewhere. Lets go back and try a 
            // different number for this particular unassigned location
            grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    // If we have gone through all possible numbers for the current unassigned
    // location, then we probably assigned a bad number early. Lets backtrack 
    // and try a different number for the previous unassigned locations.
    return false; 
}

bool solve_soduko2(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    // If the Soduko grid has been filled, we are done
    if (GRID_FULL == get_unassigned_location(grid))
    {
   //omp cancel 
        return true; 
    }

    // Get an unassigned Soduko grid location
    std::pair<int, int> row_and_col = get_unassigned_location(grid);
    int row = row_and_col.first;
    int col = row_and_col.second;

    // Consider digits 1 to 16
  #pragma omp taskloop firstprivate(grid) 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
    {
        // If placing the current number in the current
        // unassigned location is valid, go ahead
    //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    //printf("Executing thread: %d with number: %d\n" ,iam, num);
        if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            // Make tentative assignment
      //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
      //printf("Is_safe from thread: %d\n",iam);
            grid[row][col] = num;

            // Do the same thing again recursively. If we go 
            // through all of the recursions, and in the end 
            // return true, then all of our number placements 
            // on the Soduko grid are valid and we have fully
            // solved it
            if (solve_soduko3(grid))
            { 
        //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Solution from thread %d\n",iam);
        //print_grid(grid);
                //return true;
            }

            // As we were not able to validly go through all 
            // of the recursions, we must have an invalid number
            // placement somewhere. Lets go back and try a 
            // different number for this particular unassigned location
            grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    // If we have gone through all possible numbers for the current unassigned
    // location, then we probably assigned a bad number early. Lets backtrack 
    // and try a different number for the previous unassigned locations.
    return false; 
}

// Takes a partially filled-in grid and attempts to assign values to
// all unassigned locations in such a way to meet the requirements
// for Sudoku solution (non-duplication across rows, columns, and boxes) 
bool solve_soduko(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    // If the Soduko grid has been filled, we are done
    if (GRID_FULL == get_unassigned_location(grid))
    {
   //omp cancel 
        return true; 
    }

    // Get an unassigned Soduko grid location
    std::pair<int, int> row_and_col = get_unassigned_location(grid);
    int row = row_and_col.first;
    int col = row_and_col.second;

    // Consider digits 1 to 16
  #pragma omp taskloop firstprivate(grid) 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
    {
        // If placing the current number in the current
        // unassigned location is valid, go ahead
    //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    //printf("Executing thread: %d with number: %d\n" ,iam, num);
        if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            // Make tentative assignment
      //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
      //printf("Is_safe from thread: %d\n",iam);
            grid[row][col] = num;

            // Do the same thing again recursively. If we go 
            // through all of the recursions, and in the end 
            // return true, then all of our number placements 
            // on the Soduko grid are valid and we have fully
            // solved it
            if (solve_soduko2(grid))
            { 
        //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Solution from thread %d\n",iam);
        //print_grid(grid);
                //return true;
            }

            // As we were not able to validly go through all 
            // of the recursions, we must have an invalid number
            // placement somewhere. Lets go back and try a 
            // different number for this particular unassigned location
            grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    // If we have gone through all possible numbers for the current unassigned
    // location, then we probably assigned a bad number early. Lets backtrack 
    // and try a different number for the previous unassigned locations.
    return false; 
}




int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
  int n;
  if (argc > 1) {
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
  } else {
    n = 10;
  }
    cout << "********************************\n\n\tSudoku Solver\n\n********************************" << endl << endl;

  int grid[DIM][DIM] = 
               { 
               {0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
               {0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 14, 0, 1, 0, 2, 11, 0, 13 }, 
               {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 13, 8, 0, 16, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0, 11, 3, 0, 8, 14 },
               {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 0, 3, 0, 10, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12 },
               {0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9, 0, 14, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 0 },
               {0, 10, 0, 13, 0, 0, 3, 15, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 16 },
               {1, 4, 7, 0, 13, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 11 },
               {0, 7, 0, 5, 9, 6, 1, 0, 2, 8, 3, 10, 0, 14, 0, 4 },
               {0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 15, 0, 13, 0, 10 },
               {6, 3, 0, 4, 0, 15, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 0, 2 },
               {0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 11, 0, 2, 0, 16, 0, 0, 8, 3, 6, 7 },
               {0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 13, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0 },
               {5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 6, 10, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 12, 9 },
               {7, 9, 1, 6, 0, 14, 0, 11, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10, 8 },
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1, 4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7, 2, 3 }
               };

    print_grid(grid);
  
  #pragma omp parallel
  if (true == solve_soduko(grid))
  {
    print_grid(grid);
  }
  else
  {
    
  }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Using perf stat we can find this:

```
            432,05 msec task-clock                #    1,006 CPUs utilized
               212      context-switches          #    0,491 K/sec
                 7      cpu-migrations            #    0,016 K/sec
               516      page-faults               #    0,001 M/sec
     1.358.610.716      cycles                    #    3,145 GHz
       181.804.410      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   13,38% frontend cycles idle
       173.322.596      stalled-cycles-backend    #   12,76% backend cycles idle
     2.712.411.557      instructions              #    2,00  insn per cycle
                                                  #    0,07  stalled cycles per insn
     1.000.736.151      branches                  # 2316,273 M/sec
        11.188.177      branch-misses             #    1,12% of all branches

       0,429285963 seconds time elapsed

       0,403108000 seconds user
       0,030008000 seconds sys
```

Our assumption is that when using tasks, a task may randomly find a way to the solution faster than the sequential version, but these tasks appear to run sequentially and not parallel, due to the% of CPU used in the perf appears as 1.006.
The sequential version of this program takes about 28 seconds on average, while this parallel version with tasks can take less than a second at best, but can take as long as the sequential version.

We cannot figure out how to make the tasks run sequentially, we must be overlooking some important aspect in the code which we cannot see.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to get it, copying the matrix to all the task. The final code is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <omp.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define DIM 16
#define BLANK 0
#define SPACE " "
#define LINE "|"
#define NEW_ROW "----------------------------------------------------------"
#define GRID_FULL std::make_pair(16, 16)

// Prints the Soduko grid
void print_grid(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    {
        cout << SPACE << SPACE << SPACE << SPACE << endl;
        cout << NEW_ROW << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
        {
            cout << SPACE;
            if (BLANK == grid[i][j])
            {
                cout << SPACE;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << grid[i][j];
            }
            cout << SPACE;
            cout << LINE;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << NEW_ROW << endl << endl;;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether any assigned entry
// in the specified row matches the given number. 
bool used_in_row(int grid[DIM][DIM], int row, int num)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < DIM; col++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
        {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether any assigned entry
// in the specified column matches the given number. 
bool used_in_col(int grid[DIM][DIM], int col, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < DIM; row++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
        {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether any assigned entry
// within the specified 3x3 box matches the given number. 
bool used_in_box(int grid[DIM][DIM], int box_start_rpw, int box_start_col, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            if (grid[row + box_start_rpw][col + box_start_col] == num) 
            {
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}

// Returns a boolean which indicates whether it will be legal to assign
// num to the given row,col location.
bool is_safe(int grid[DIM][DIM], int row, int col, int num)
{
    // Check if 'num' is not already placed in current row,
    // current column and current 3x3 box 
    return !used_in_row(grid, row, num) &&
        !used_in_col(grid, col, num) &&
        !used_in_box(grid, row - row % 4, col - col % 4, num);
}

// Searches the grid to find an entry that is still unassigned. If
// found, the reference parameters row, col will be set the location
// that is unassigned, and true is returned. If no unassigned entries
// remain, false is returned. 
std::pair<int, int> get_unassigned_location(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < DIM; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < DIM; col++)
            if (grid[row][col] == BLANK)
            {
                return std::make_pair(row, col);
            }
    return GRID_FULL;
}

bool solve_soduko3(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    // If the Soduko grid has been filled, we are done
    if (GRID_FULL == get_unassigned_location(grid))
    {
   //omp cancel 
        return true; 
    }

    // Get an unassigned Soduko grid location
    std::pair<int, int> row_and_col = get_unassigned_location(grid);
    int row = row_and_col.first;
    int col = row_and_col.second;

    // Consider digits 1 to 16 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
    {
        // If placing the current number in the current
        // unassigned location is valid, go ahead
    //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    //printf("Executing thread: %d with number: %d\n" ,iam, num);
        if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            // Make tentative assignment
      //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
      //printf("Is_safe from thread: %d\n",iam);
            grid[row][col] = num;

            // Do the same thing again recursively. If we go 
            // through all of the recursions, and in the end 
            // return true, then all of our number placements 
            // on the Soduko grid are valid and we have fully
            // solved it
            if (solve_soduko3(grid))
            { 
        //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Solution from thread %d\n",iam);
        print_grid(grid);
                exit(true);
        return true;
            }

            // As we were not able to validly go through all 
            // of the recursions, we must have an invalid number
            // placement somewhere. Lets go back and try a 
            // different number for this particular unassigned location
            grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    // If we have gone through all possible numbers for the current unassigned
    // location, then we probably assigned a bad number early. Lets backtrack 
    // and try a different number for the previous unassigned locations.
    return false; 
}

bool solve_soduko2(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    // If the Soduko grid has been filled, we are done
    if (GRID_FULL == get_unassigned_location(grid))
    {
   //omp cancel 
        return true; 
    }

    // Get an unassigned Soduko grid location
    std::pair<int, int> row_and_col = get_unassigned_location(grid);
    int row = row_and_col.first;
    int col = row_and_col.second;

    // Consider digits 1 to 16
  #pragma omp taskloop firstprivate(grid) 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
    {
        // If placing the current number in the current
        // unassigned location is valid, go ahead
    //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    //printf("Executing thread: %d with number: %d\n" ,iam, num);
        if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            // Make tentative assignment
      //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
      //printf("Is_safe from thread: %d\n",iam);
            grid[row][col] = num;

            // Do the same thing again recursively. If we go 
            // through all of the recursions, and in the end 
            // return true, then all of our number placements 
            // on the Soduko grid are valid and we have fully
            // solved it
            if (solve_soduko3(grid))
            { 
        //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Solution from thread %d\n",iam);
        //print_grid(grid);
                //return true;
            }

            // As we were not able to validly go through all 
            // of the recursions, we must have an invalid number
            // placement somewhere. Lets go back and try a 
            // different number for this particular unassigned location
            grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    // If we have gone through all possible numbers for the current unassigned
    // location, then we probably assigned a bad number early. Lets backtrack 
    // and try a different number for the previous unassigned locations.
    return false; 
}

// Takes a partially filled-in grid and attempts to assign values to
// all unassigned locations in such a way to meet the requirements
// for Sudoku solution (non-duplication across rows, columns, and boxes) 
bool solve_soduko(int grid[DIM][DIM])
{
    // If the Soduko grid has been filled, we are done
    if (GRID_FULL == get_unassigned_location(grid))
    {
   //omp cancel 
        return true; 
    }

    // Get an unassigned Soduko grid location
    std::pair<int, int> row_and_col = get_unassigned_location(grid);
    int row = row_and_col.first;
    int col = row_and_col.second;

    // Consider digits 1 to 16
  #pragma omp taskloop firstprivate(grid) 
    for (int num = 1; num <= 16; num++)
    {
        // If placing the current number in the current
        // unassigned location is valid, go ahead
    //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    //printf("Executing thread: %d with number: %d\n" ,iam, num);
        if (is_safe(grid, row, col, num))
        {
            // Make tentative assignment
      //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
      //printf("Is_safe from thread: %d\n",iam);
            grid[row][col] = num;

            // Do the same thing again recursively. If we go 
            // through all of the recursions, and in the end 
            // return true, then all of our number placements 
            // on the Soduko grid are valid and we have fully
            // solved it
            if (solve_soduko2(grid))
            { 
        //int iam = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Solution from thread %d\n",iam);
        //print_grid(grid);
                //return true;
            }

            // As we were not able to validly go through all 
            // of the recursions, we must have an invalid number
            // placement somewhere. Lets go back and try a 
            // different number for this particular unassigned location
            grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    // If we have gone through all possible numbers for the current unassigned
    // location, then we probably assigned a bad number early. Lets backtrack 
    // and try a different number for the previous unassigned locations.
    return false; 
}




int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
  int n;
  if (argc > 1) {
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
  } else {
    n = 10;
  }
    cout << "********************************\n\n\tSudoku Solver\n\n********************************" << endl << endl;

  int grid[DIM][DIM] = 
               { 
               {0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
               {0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 14, 0, 1, 0, 2, 11, 0, 13 }, 
               {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 13, 8, 0, 16, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0, 11, 3, 0, 8, 14 },
               {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 11, 0, 3, 0, 10, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12 },
               {0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9, 0, 14, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 0 },
               {0, 10, 0, 13, 0, 0, 3, 15, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 16 },
               {1, 4, 7, 0, 13, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 11 },
               {0, 7, 0, 5, 9, 6, 1, 0, 2, 8, 3, 10, 0, 14, 0, 4 },
               {0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 15, 0, 13, 0, 10 },
               {6, 3, 0, 4, 0, 15, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 12, 0, 2 },
               {0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 11, 0, 2, 0, 16, 0, 0, 8, 3, 6, 7 },
               {0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 13, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0 },
               {5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 6, 10, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 12, 9 },
               {7, 9, 1, 6, 0, 14, 0, 11, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10, 8 },
               {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1, 4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7, 2, 3 }
               };

    print_grid(grid);
  
  #pragma omp parallel
  if (true == solve_soduko(grid))
  {
    print_grid(grid);
  }
  else
  {
    
  }
  
    return 0;
}
```